# HTML-Content doesn't apply CSS after insert with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get the page content for a specific page from a database.
That works perfect but now my problem:

For the 'Contact'-Page, I'm getting a form (just HTML...) from the database. But it ignores the CSS, I've loaded in the head of the page.
The form-parts have IDs and classes.

My thought is, that it is caused by the insert of content **after** I loaded the CSS.

**Note:** I'm not using JQuery and I don't want to use it in this project.

The form looks like the following:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<label id="CLabel" for="sendname">Name:<span class="required"></span></label><input type="text" class="contact" name="sendname" maxlength="30" required placeholder="Your Name..(Required)"><br>
<label id="CLabel" for="sendemail">Email:<span class="required"></span></label><input type="email" class="contact" name="sendemail" maxlength="100" placeholder="Your Email-address.."><br>
<label id="CLabel" for="reason">Contact reason:</label><input type="text" class="contact" name="sendreason" maxlength="30" required placeholder="Your Reason..(Required)"><br>
<label id="CLabel" for="sendmsg"></label><textarea id="cmsg" class="noResize" name="sendmsg" required placeholder="Your Message..(Required)" onfocus="this.value=\"\"; this.onfocus=null;"></textarea><br>
<label id="CLabel" for="contactbutton"></label><input class="contactbutton" type="submit" name="contactbutton" value="Send">
</form>
```

To take a look on the CSS or Javascript, check the link:
[philliprohde.bugs3.com/new_/](http://philliprohde.bugs3.com/new_/)

The css is the following (With changed id to class):

```
label.CLabel{
display:inline-block;
width: 7em;
}
input.contact{
width:400px;
margin-top:5px;
}
/* Button of the contact form */
.contactbutton{
width: 100px;
background: #c1c1c1;
color: #8b0000;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-shadow: #000 1px 1px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
textarea.noResize { resize:none; }
textarea#cmsg {
width: 400px;
height: 120px;
margin-top:5px;
border:none;
font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

Solved. The hoster hasn't accepted my new css-file (I don't know why). 
I deleted the old, uploaded it again and now it works.

Thank you for your support.!

Comment: [**ID MUST BE UNIQUE**](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/tests/test185.html)

Comment: I haven't looked at the css, but first issue is that the labels all have the same `id`

Comment: inserting content after loading the CSS is not a problem

Comment: @steven: The link isn't broken, but my hoster has obiously problems.

Comment: @kevmc: Okay, thank you, I will fix that, but this won't solve it I think.

Comment: Just leave the initial www away and the link works fine. I can't find any particular styles, that should be applied to the form in your stylesheets except from the general #content_content styles, which are applied. Please post the styles that should be applied and point out where they can be found.

Comment: By the way: your ajax results in loading data twice into the page. The google analytics code and the no-script part for example.

Comment: @bouscher: I can't prevent the page from inserting the google analytics code. It is automatically generated and inserted from the hoster. Why it appears in the ajax result? I don't know.

Fixed the link and added the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- Your preview link isn't working;
- The markup you've posted isn't valid (you're reusing the ID 'CLabel' for your labels).

Neither of these should impact your CSS, although the multi-IDs could raise a few issues for you elsewhere in the development.

Adding content into a page after the load will be styled by any CSS you've got in the page (that's relevant) .

Here's what I would suggest you look for to debug:

- Is it possible that the CSS isn't actually being included as you expect?  Open up Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools and make sure you're not getting any errors when the CSS passes through.
- Is it possible that your CSS isn't targetting the new content correctly?
- It isn't obvious from your question (at the moment), but is it possible that you're loading the content in via an iFrame (in which case the CSS of the parent page wouldn't effect it).

Comment: See my note in the question.

And I'm not loading the content into an iFrame. (I don't like iFrames.)